# Binary tree with classes

Tags: c++, class, tree

I have this piece of code:

```
class Node{
public:
    Square square;
    Node *NW;
    Node *NE;
    Node *SW;
    Node *SE;

};

int main()
{
    Square s(2,3,1);
    Node *root;

    root->square=s;
    cout<<root->square.length();

}
```

Square is a class I created. But when I run this code I get segmentation fault 11. Basically I want to use an object of class Square, as data type of a tree, and length is a function of the square object. Why is this wrong?

Comment: I guess you need to read up on how to use pointers correctly.  The issue has nothing to do with Squares and Nodes.

Comment: The branches appear to have four children, so the structure is actually a quaternary tree.

Comment: The issue has everything to do with NULL pointers, allocating memory and making your pointers point to *valid* objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare your `Node` on the stack

```
int main()
{
    Square s(2,3,1);
    Node root;

    root.square = s;
    cout << root.square.length();
}
```

The current problem is that you're using an uninitialized, unallocated pointer. If you want to stick to a pointer (which there's no reason to in this case), you'd need to `new` it (then remember to `delete` it too).

```
int main()
{
    Square s(2,3,1);
    Node *root = new Node;

    root->square = s;
    cout << root->square.length();

    delete root;
}
```

In modern C++ if you do need a pointer (e.g. if the class is polymorphic, etc) you should prefer a smart pointer instead of a raw pointer.

```
int main()
{
    Square s(2,3,1);
    auto root = std::make_unique<Node>();

    root->square = s;
    cout << root->square.length();
}
```

Comment: I tried the first option but I get this:  implicit default constructor for 'Node' must explicitly
      initialize the member 'square' which does not have a default constructor

Answer (score 0):

```
root = new node;
root -> squares = s;
delete root;
root = NULL;
```

You need to allocate memory for the pointer. You are trying to dereference a pointer that hasn't been allocated. That's why you are segfaulting.

Comment: kindly add a delete